# How do I use scikit-build to compile an extension module as part of another setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

I have a python package which has several modules, including one library that is currently building using scikit-build and cmake. It works nicely for local development, but I'm trying to figure out how to build it as part of a distribution. Can somebody explain how to use scikit-build as part of a larger python distribution?

Comment: You use `skbuild.setup` instead of `setuptools.setup` and configure the rest of args as usual.

Comment: For now that won't work for me. I'm using more than one extension module, and it looks like scikit-build would expect one CMakeLists.txt. Currently I compile multiple extensions modules with multiple setup.py, but it would be nice to specify all the extensions in one setup.py